# Handling Extra column data in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have an excel with 10 columns(Headers) as 6th column is empty column.
When I converted to text file, I got 9 columns(Removing empty column) but the data rows are 10.
How can I handle to exclude empty data row

Comment: can you provide a sample of the text file you are trying to load?

Comment: Name|Gender   
Alex| |Male   
Sam| |Male   



In between Name and Gender there is a empty cell in cell,after conversion the text file doesn't contains  empty header but it contains empty cell.

Comment: A few options... Delete the column before creating text file. Or start processing data on row 2 and skip headers. You will have to rename them manually or work with the default names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional split transformation :

- Rename the Output Name to : Remove all empty rows
- Set the condition
  to : `ISNULL(Col1) && ISNULL(Col2) && .... && ISNULL(ColN)`
- When connecting your “Conditional Split” to your destination, SSIS will ask you what output the “Conditional Split” needs to return. To output the entire set without the empty rows, chose the “Conditional Split Default Output”:
  [image]